# USACO Printing Problem: Could Not Find/Load Main Class

Tags: java

On my computer, the program successfully writes to a file named friday.out with the correct solutions. However, the USACO website tells me that "Error:_Could_not_find_or_load_main_class_friday".

I've tried making the class public and deleting the word public (doesn't make a difference). The program compiles without any errors.

```
package friday;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class friday {

    static boolean leapYear = false; //Are we on a leap year
    public static boolean leapYearTest(int year) {
        if(year%100==0 && year%400==0) {
            leapYear = true;
        }
        else if(year%100==0 && year%400 != 0) {
            leapYear = false;
        }
        else if(year%100!=0 && year%4==0) {
            leapYear = true;
        }
        else if(year%100!=0 && year%4!=0) {
            leapYear = false;
        }
        return leapYear;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("friday.in"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("friday.out")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int years = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); //Number of years
        int endYear = 1900+years-1;
        int currentYear = 1900;
        int currentDay = 1; //Jan 1. day = 1
        int currentMonth = 1; //Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc.
        int currentStringDay = 1; //Mon = 1, Tues = 2, etc.
        int totalDays = 0;
        //For loop figures out number of days
        for(int i=1900;i<=endYear;i++) {
            if(leapYearTest(i)==true) {
                totalDays+=366;
            }
            else if(leapYearTest(i)==false) {
                totalDays+=365;
            }
        }
        //End for loop
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> regMonths = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        regMonths.put(1, 31);
        regMonths.put(2, 28);
        regMonths.put(3, 31);
        regMonths.put(4, 30);
        regMonths.put(5, 31);
        regMonths.put(6, 30);
        regMonths.put(7, 31);
        regMonths.put(8, 31);
        regMonths.put(9, 30);
        regMonths.put(10, 31);
        regMonths.put(11, 30);
        regMonths.put(12, 31);
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> leapMonths = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        leapMonths.put(1, 31);
        leapMonths.put(2, 29);
        leapMonths.put(3, 31);
        leapMonths.put(4, 30);
        leapMonths.put(5, 31);
        leapMonths.put(6, 30);
        leapMonths.put(7, 31);
        leapMonths.put(8, 31);
        leapMonths.put(9, 30);
        leapMonths.put(10, 31);
        leapMonths.put(11, 30);
        leapMonths.put(12, 31);
        int SatCounter = 0; //Saturday Counter
        int SunCounter = 0;
        int MonCounter = 0;
        int TuesCounter = 0;
        int WedCounter = 0;
        int ThurCounter = 0;
        int FriCounter = 0;
        for(int i = currentDay;i<=totalDays;i++) {
            if(i%7==0) {
                currentStringDay=7;
            }
            else if(i%7!=0) {
                currentStringDay=i%7;
            }
            //if(currentDay == 13 && currentStringDay == 5) {
            if(currentDay == 13) {
                if(currentStringDay == 6) {
                    SatCounter+=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 7) {
                    SunCounter+=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 1) {
                    MonCounter+=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 2) {
                    TuesCounter +=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 3) {
                    WedCounter+=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 4) {
                    ThurCounter+=1;
                }
                if(currentStringDay == 5) {
                    FriCounter+=1;
                }

            }

            if(leapYearTest(currentYear)==false) {
                //use regMonths
                if(currentDay<regMonths.get(currentMonth)) {
                    currentDay+=1;
                }
                else if(currentDay==regMonths.get(currentMonth)) {
                    currentDay=1;
                    if(currentMonth<12) {
                        currentMonth+=1;
                    }
                    else if(currentMonth == 12) {
                        currentMonth = 1;
                    }
                    if(currentMonth == 1) {
                        currentYear+=1;
                        currentDay=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(leapYearTest(currentYear)==true) {
                //use leapMonths
                if(currentDay<leapMonths.get(currentMonth)) {
                    currentDay+=1;
                }
                else if(currentDay==leapMonths.get(currentMonth)) {
                    currentDay=1;
                    if(currentMonth<12) {
                        currentMonth+=1;
                    }
                    else if(currentMonth == 12) {
                        currentMonth = 1;
                    }
                    if(currentMonth == 1) {
                        currentYear+=1;
                        currentDay=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        out.println(SatCounter+" "+SunCounter+" "+MonCounter+" "+TuesCounter+" "+WedCounter+" "+ThurCounter+" "+FriCounter);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind testing following the Java code convention? Also changing the file name to Friday. public class Friday

Comment: @ngueno I tried that as well and nothing changed.

Comment: I do not know much about USACO, but how are you running it on your system (command line, IDE, etc.)  You might want to look at the concept of a classpath: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: try to give complete path `friday.friday`, and i will recommend you to have different name for class and package, at least follow some standards

Comment: @KellyMarchewa I am running it through Eclipse.

Comment: @Deadpool I can't change the class name because that is how USACO grades the files. How do you change the program so I can have a complete path as you mentioned?

Comment: @Jay, how do you upload the program to USACO? As a JAR? If so, how are you creating the JAR?

Comment: @KellyMarchewa I upload it as a .java file. This is the pathway: C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\friday\src\friday

Comment: .java files are not compiled. You have to compile them  or package them as an executable JAR to run the program. For example, `javac C:/Users/MYNAME/src/friday/friday.java'.`

Comment: @KellyMarchewa I solved the problem! USACO simply did not want the package statement at the top. "package friday;"

Comment: Glad to hear it and welcome to the StackOverflow community; I trust it will be a great asset to your in your programming journey. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just stating Jay's comment as an answer since it also worked for me.  Make sure your file does not include the package statement at the top of your class.